# Sum of Random Integers

Tags: random, education, infinite-loop

I am trying to get a list of numbers with at least 1000 sums as possible, using random numbers from 1 to 10. But I don't want to get blank list output.

How can I only get a list of numbers greater than 1000 in total?
I think my loop is insufficient.

Here is my code:

```
m = {};
n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 170];
liste = Total[n];
While[liste >= 1000, AppendTo[m, n]; Break[];]
m
liste
```

Comment: Yes, I think your loop is insufficient, too :)  It's not perfectly clear to me what you want, but maybe it's this?: `While[n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 170]; Total[n] < 1000,]; n`

Comment: `RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 1000]` is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Or: `Reap[sum = 0; 
  While[sum < 1000, sum += (n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]); Sow[n]]][[2, 
  1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to output just one number with your conditions try

```
liste = 0;
While[liste < 1000, n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 170];
liste = Total[n]]
liste
n
```

here is the result and the 170 numbers that add up to this result
If you don't want all these numbers to be displayed, just remove the last n from the code

> 1020
>
> {4,4,10,4,4,9,9,4,2,2,10,8,8,2,2,1,3,6,3,8,7,8,4,1,6,1,5,3,9,9,1,9,2,3,10,10,3,10,6,10,10,9,10,10,2,6,7,1,5,9,8,5,3,8,10,8,1,1,10,6,7,10,3,7,7,5,9,3,10,10,6,6,5,3,9,10,1,8,1,8,4,9,1,4,9,8,7,2,9,5,6,3,10,10,10,5,3,6,6,4,1,10,3,4,10,4,10,5,10,10,5,5,9,1,10,5,9,5,5,5,7,8,1,3,2,8,10,9,9,6,2,9,5,5,6,10,1,5,7,7,7,3,7,7,4,10,5,8,2,1,8,9,8,2,5,10,1,2,7,9,8,9,3,8,8,3,10,2,6,4}

Answer (score 5):

```
var = Array[x, 170];

dud = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 10}];
```

Since you want the sum ([`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)) of the 170 variables to be at least 1000 and the most the sum could be is 1700, then the distribution for the truncated sum is

```
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{1000, 1700},
   TransformedDistribution[Total[var],
    Thread[Distributed[var, dud]]]];
```

To get a list of 1000 random draws from this distribution

```
SeedRandom[0]

list = RandomVariate[dist, 1000];

Mean[list] // N

(* 1015.98 *)

Median[list]

(* 1012 *)

Histogram[list]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at your problem could be in terms of making a series of experiment. Then understanding the likelihood that the sum of 170 integers is greater than 1000. The code would then be:

```
res = Table[{i, RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 10}], 170]}, {i,
 1, 100}]; 
Select[(Total@#[[2]]) >= 1000 &]@ res
```